# Apply a bootstrap class in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap's classes many times in my application for buttons or forms but the "active" class somehow does not seem to work. Here is what I have from bootstrap which render the desired layouts

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to keep the "active" class in my view with the two following syntax

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path, class: "active" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><%= link_to "Home", home_path, class: "nav nav-tabs active" %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %></li>
</ul>
```

but neither of both work. Would anyone know why and provide me with the appropriate syntax? Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "neither of both work"? That it is not showing as active (blue or whatever color) or it does not switch from tab to tab? Because the first version in your question should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks all. I want to add the tag within a rails method as I want in a second step put conditions (such as a current state) to get the tag active. This will not work in html.

Comment: Then my answer is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I do while dealing with bootstrap navigation. First, I create a helper "is_active?" in my application helper:

application_helper.rb

```
def is_active?(link_path)
  current_page?(link_path) ? "active" : ""
end
```

The in ul element I do the following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="<%= is_active? home_path %>">
    <%= link_to "Home", home_path %>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= is_active? profile_path %>">
    <%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see I am passing home_path to "is_active?" method that compares it with the current page path. And if they are the same adds the 'active' class to the li element.

**And you can DRY it even further:**

application_helper.rb

```
# as before
def is_active?(link_path)
  current_page?(link_path) ? "active" : ""
end

def nav_link(title, link_path)
  content_tag(:li, link_to(title, link_path, class: is_active?(link_path)))
end
```

Your menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <%= nav_link("Home", home_path) %>
  <%= nav_link("Profile", profile_path) %>
</ul>
```

**And even further:**

```
<%
  # all your titles and paths are here
  menu = {"Home" => home_path, "Profile" => profile_path}
%>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <% menu.each do |title, path| %>
    <%= nav_link(title, path) %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `active` class is on your `<li>` tag instead of the `link_to`. `link_to` will generate your `<a>` tag.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Home", home_path %></li>
  <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">item#1</li> //this will be shown as active
  <li>item#2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to "Home", home_path%></li>
  <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path %></li>
</ul>
```

You need to add class and role to li not with the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. You helped me find what I wanted. I indeed need to apply the class on

not on the link_to method. In order to remain on a rails method I can use the content_tag method (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) to apply the class to the

tag.

Comment: I just realized that my code can be DRYed some more. I will make it cleaner  in a bit. I just have to try the right syntax. I will let you know when it is done.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a DRY way of doing it.